# Calling a method based on variables Blazor

Tags: c#, html, blazor

I need to call a method from the text entered by the user. Below is the code but something is not working.

```
@page "/DodawanieElementu"
@using VikkingWebApp.Data;
@inject VikkingServices VikkingOkucia
<h3>DodawanieElementu</h3>
<p> dodaj okucie z bazy: </p>
<input type="text" @bind:="@kod" />
<button @onclick="Search">Confirm</button>
@code {
    protected string kod;
    async Task Search()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => VikkingOkucia.Dodajelement(kod));
    }


}
```

Comment: You gain nothing by using `await Task.Run` in a web app, whether it runs on the server or browser. On the server, every request is already served by a separate thread. On the browser, there's only a single thread unless you use workers. Convert `Dodajelement` to a real asynchronous method, using asynchronous methods like `HttpClient.GetAsycn`, EF's `ToListAsync` or `ADO.NET's `ExecuteReaderAsync` instead of their synchronous counterparts

Comment: `kod` itself is a field, not a variable. Its value will change if the component it's bound to changes BUT `@bind:="@kod"` is invalid syntax. It should be ` @bind="@kod"`. Even then, the search results don't seem to be used in any way, so even if the search succeeds, you won't notice

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to start with the [official Blazor tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and quickstarts. The Blazor project templates already show how you can use inputs and call remote services, eg in the Weather Forecast  component. Data Binding is explained in detail in the [ASP.NET Core Blazor Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) page

Comment: I'm just starting my adventure with programming and I'm doing it for myself. There are many things I don't understand yet. There is always something that can be improved, to do something better, but it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: All the more reason to start with a library's tutorials and quickstarts, check the template code. Otherwise even a typo like `@bind:=` can cause a lot of trouble. In this case the typo hides the fact that the results are never used.

Comment: "_something_ is not working" is not precise enough in a question. Post full error messages or  actual vs expected outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your code have already been documented in the comments.

Here's a demo based on your search box and the `FetchData` page.

Modified `WeatherService` Data Provider.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastService
{
    private List<WeatherForecast> _forecasts;

    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    public WeatherForecastService()
    {
        _forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now).AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToList();
    }

    public Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_forecasts.AsEnumerable());
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastsAsync(string? search)
    {
        var forecasts = await GetForecastAsync();
        return forecasts.Where(item => (item.Summary ?? string.Empty).Contains(search ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

Refactored `FetchData`.

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SO77007361.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" @bind="_searchTerm" /> <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.Search">Search</button>
</div>

<div>No Button Alternative</div>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" @bind="_searchTerm" @bind:after="Search" />
</div>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private string? _searchTerm;
    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>? forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync();
    }

    private async Task Search()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastsAsync(_searchTerm);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take @PanagiotisKanavos advice on tutorials.  [Polite] Stack Overflow is not a free training centre.